# Execute cronjob inside php

Tags: php, email, cron

How can I run a php script only once inside a php file, where it executes the cronjob once a certain action is done by the user.  I have the interactions already set up, all I need to do is have a php function called within a cronjob after the user does this certain action.

I want to loop through all users inside my database with a certain forgein key attatched to them, and send them an email.

Also, is it possible to have a cronjob written in PHP

My code is as follows.

```
$i = 0;
$queryResult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query);
while($i<mysqli_num_rows($queryResult) ) {
$inf_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult);
$brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM brands WHERE id = '$brand_id'"));
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'crowdfluenceapp@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'qtDa5LOM';
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SetFrom(EMAIL_USERNAME, "Crowdfluence Support");
$mail->addAddress($inf_info['email'], $inf_info['first_name'] . " " . $inf_info['last_name']);
$mail->Subject = "Your insider brand has started an internal campaign!";
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->Body = "
Greetings influencer! We want to let you know that that your insider brand, " . $brand['name'] . ",<br><br>

Has started a new insider campaign.<br><br>

If you wish to not participate, simply ignore this email.<br><br>

Sincerely,<br><br>

The Crowdfluence Team
";
// Check if email was sent successfully
if ($mail->send()){
unset($mail);
}else{
unset($mail);
}
$i +=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run PHP scripts via normal Linux cronjob.

If you wanted to run a PHP script every minute, on most standard linux servers the syntax would be something like:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/script/myscript.php
```

If you are using some shared hosting provider, and don't have access to the server/container where PHP is running, you might find cronjob support in the cpanel/webmin etc.

You can 'emulate' a cronjob using just PHP, but it is not very reliable.  One way I've seen it done is to host a page somewhere on your server say http://mywebsite.com/cron/cron.php, and use an external service that does health checks, like Pingdom/AWS Route53, which will reliably hit the page every x minutes.

If you just want to prevent a script from running too often, you can write a timestamp to a database or file when the script runs, and check if enough seconds have passed since the last time the script ran.

If you want a page to return, and then do some background processing (also useful in the fake cronjob styles above), such as send out emails, you can use the PHP function [ignore_user_abort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) to let return a success message, and then continue to process the requests.  This can also be used to get more incremental crons, if you wanted something to run every 30 seconds, etc.

Comment: Also you can add **locks** here as sometimes crons may take longer than usual to complete and meanwhile the clock already hits for the next run. This would create inconsistencies and race conditions so better have a (lock)file that you create on each run and delete when all job is done. So if next cron happens while 1st one's still in progress you just skip this time. But also sometimes script might crash in those case you set a "hard limit" so if lock file is older than say 2 days you just ignore it, delete that lock , create a new one and proceed as usual